# How to toggle a pin (LED) simply

Tags: pins

I am not a programmer but rather a hardware guy. In the good old machine code days, you could 'read' the status of the port and flip it.. admittedly a much simpler processor. Is it not possible to do this with the 328 without many lines of code?

Comment: When you google for "Arduino toggle pin" you will get good results. When doing it the Arduino way it would be: `digitalWrite(pinToToggle, !digitalRead(pinToToggle));`

Comment: The other cores apart of oficial ones often provides toggle funcionality. And if you don't like super slow arduino functions, you can access ports directly (for example if you write something to PINx it'll toggle corresponding bits on PORTx)

Comment: what @KIIV said ... official info is at section 17.2.2 of https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001906A.pdf

Answer (score 2):

It is perfectly possible to do this without "many lines of code". The ATMega328P is actually a pretty simple chip (certainly by today's standards). Reading and writing pins is just the same as it has always been - read a port's byte value from the PINx register, modify it, and write it back to the PORTx register.

Much of what the Arduino API does is abstract things to make complex operations simpler. One side effect is it can make simple operations seem more complex (and in fact can slow things down as a result). But you don't *have* to always use the Arduino API for everything.

It is common to directly manipulate the IO registers to perform higher speed manipulation of the IO pins especially when you want to do such things as emulate other communication protocols, or shrink your code to fit into a really small microcontroller with as little flash usage as possible.

Answer (score 2):

To toggle a pin, just read the pjn and invert the value:

```
#define LEDPIN 2

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, !digitalRead(LEDPIN));
}
```

You can also just "remember" the last value:

```
#define LEDPIN 2
bool led_on = false;
unsigned long led_time = 500; // 1/2 sec on and 1/2 sec off
unsigned long lasttime = 0; // last millis() time we turned the led off or on

void setup() {
    digitalWrite(LEDPIN, LOW);
    pinMode(LEDPIN, OUTPUT);
}
void loop() {
    unsigned long now = millis();
    if (lasttime - now > led_time) {
        led_on = !led_on;
        digitalWrite(LEDPIN, led_on);
        last_time = now;
    }
}
```